# Conversion of HTML as text to json

Tags: javascript, html, json

A request returns html tags as text and i am wondering how i can covert that text to json or something else usable. So the request returns this type of text:

```
"<ul> <li>Coffee</li> <li>Tea</li> <li>Milk</li> </ul>"
```

Is there a way i can convert that text inn to something usable with javascript? And some requests return much bigger chunks of html text as well.

I have tried to split on this text up but i have not achived anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to treat the HTML as XML document, then convert it to JSON. I used an available [JSON convert function](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) and applied it to your text snippet, and it fits hopefully well. This could be an approach that would fit your needs.

```js
let htmlContent = '<ul> <li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li> </ul>';

function xmlToJson(xml) {
    
    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof(obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

function parseXml(xml) {
   var dom = null;
   if (window.DOMParser) {
      try { 
         dom = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"); 
      } 
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      try {
         dom = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
         dom.async = false;
         if (!dom.loadXML(xml)) // parse error ..

            window.alert(dom.parseError.reason + dom.parseError.srcText);
      } 
      catch (e) { dom = null; }
   }
   else
      alert("cannot parse xml string!");
   return dom;
};



let dom = parseXml(htmlContent);
let json = xmlToJson(dom);
console.log(json);
```